# Automatically add one year to date column when item is created

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have a date column where I want it to automatically populate with the date from today plus 1 year.
For example, if the todays date is 31 august 2020 the value of the date column will be set 31 august 2021.

What is the calculating value for the above?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
=DATE(YEAR([Date])+1,MONTH([Date]),DAY([Date]))
```

Try this.

Here [Date] is the date Sharepoint  column

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)

Answer (score 1):

The formula of calculated value should be this:

```
=DATE(YEAR(Today)+1,MONTH(Today),DAY(Today))
```